# Struggling with SQL syntax - what am I missing please? (Novice to SQL here)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to extract data from an old table into a new, customer notes from an old system into a new...
I have two tables and simply want to compare email addresses held in one table to insert the relevant notes into the new table.

But the SQL below throws an error and I'm hoping it's simple for someone much more experienced than me, to spot...

SQL query:

```
UPDATE JB_hikashop_user
SET ourusernotes = JB_old_customers.oldNotes
FROM JB_hikashop_user
LEFT JOIN JB_old_customers
ON JB_hikashop_user.user_email = JB_old_customers.exEmail
WHERE JB_hikashop_user.user_email = JB_old_customers.exEmail
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM JB_hikashop_user
>   LEFT JOIN JB_old_customers
>   ON JB_hikashop_user.user_emai' at line 3**

I'm in danger of despair here... such a simple thing, but I'm stuck!

Comment: MySQL follows the syntax `UPDATE <...> INNER JOIN <...> SET <...>`

Comment: Thank you Raymond

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` queries don't have a `FROM` clause, the table after `UPDATE` serves that purpose.

The `SET` clause has to be after the `UPDATE` and `JOIN` clauses. Even though SQL looks like English, and you'd think that it could be flexible about the order of clauses, it's actually very rigid about it.

```
UPDATE JB_hikashop_user
LEFT JOIN JB_old_customers ON JB_hikashop_user.user_email = JB_old_customers.exEmail
SET ourusernotes = JB_old_customers.oldNotes
WHERE JB_hikashop_user.user_email = JB_old_customers.exEmail
```

Comment: Thank you Bamar! Your answer worked perfectly and I appreciate the explanation.